# Isolate particles from fixed bed CT scan

Tags: particles

this is my first post, but as a silent reader I learned a lot, so first of all: Thank you, you are awesome!

I now have a problem, which I don't know if it belongs here, but I'll give it a shot:

For scientific researches my group did a CT scan of a tube filled with hundreds of hexagonial prisms (a so called 'fixed bed'). The goal is to compare this 'real world' filling with filling simulations done with Blender (works great btw ;) ).
Unfortunately, the .stl-file provided by the CT scan lacks of 'resolution' (see the attached image): You can see the different pellets, but when you look at the contact points/edges/faces, you see that the surfaces bake together, which is not what we want. We want a closed surface for every single pellet (with empyt spaces between). A CT scanner with higher resolution might solve this problem, but I am curious if there is another solution based on software and smart people.

So long story short: Is there an algorithm/ workflow in Blender which can detect shapes and isolate them from each other? Or do you know another software which is more suitable?

I am grateful for every single idea!
Cheers,

Leo[image: CT scan: Fixed Bed]

Comment: This is more of a https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ question. My thought is to use an iterative algorithm depending on the data source(Point-cloud, mesh, CT-Slices?) .Find best fitting hexagonal prism, (get orientation, position, scale? remove contained geometry find next best fitting prism). I would guess, that working of the slices themselves is easiest, as the intersection between the prism and the slice will probably give you a characteristic hexagonal shape from which you can guess orientation of the prism.

Comment: Can you provide a wireframe or edit mode image. Interesting q, some iterative routine to reduce to edges of two known lengths, and 2 known face shapes. Can you add a sample file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com